# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to blinking cursor. Can get into tty2 but can't get desktop back

Tags: boot, 20.04

I allowed Ubuntu to automatically install updates today. Upon rebooting, I know longer get a GUI desktop. Only a blinking cursor. I can get into tty2 with Ctrl + Alt + F1

I tried purging gdm/gdm3, apt update, reinstalling gdm/gdm3, reinstalling xorg/xserver, per some suggestions on other threads I found.

Any advice?

Running on an older machine, Dell Precision T7500 (nvidia gpu, xeon cpu)

Comment: Nothing in it seems to be working. I found that even using the Try Ubuntu option of a bootable USB does not work?

Comment: what does your `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` say?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. After the update I was getting defaulted to the 5.8 kernel which no longer supports the rather old quadro NVS 420 in this machine. I can load force it to load 5.4 in GRUB.